# How can i get the sum of the array i declare in the range function?

Tags: javascript

I've made the range function which gives me the integers between `start` and `end`. Now i have to make a `sum` function, that takes `range` as a parameter and gives the sum of that.

```
function range(start, end) {

    let numbers = [];

    for(i=start; i <= end; i++) {

        numbers.push(i);

    }
    return numbers;
}
console.log(range(1,5));

function sum(arrayOfNumbers) {

    var sumOfNo;

    for(i=0; i <= arrayOfNumbers; i++) {
        
        arrayOfNumbers += sumOfNo;
    }

    return sumOfNo;
}
console.log(sum(range(10,15)));
```

Comment: `i=0` is missing a variable declaration (in both functions), `sumOfNo` needs to be initialised with `0`, `i <= arrayOfNumbers` needs to be `i < arrayOfNumbers.length`, and `arrayOfNumbers += sumOfNo;` needs to be `sumOfNo += arrayOfNumbers[i];`

Comment: Try [using a debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)!

Answer (score 1):

you can use reduce for this

```js
function range(start, end) {

  let numbers = [];

  for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {

    numbers.push(i);

  }
  return numbers;
}
console.log(range(10, 15));

function sum(arrayOfNumbers) {

  return arrayOfNumbers.reduce((a, n) => {
    return a += n;
  }, 0)
}
console.log(sum(range(2, 4)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Some errors I find from the code (in sum function)

- for loop need to loop less than arrayOfNumbers.length not arrayOfNumbers
- values need to be added to the sumOfNo not the other way around.

the following resolves it.

```js
function range(start, end) {

    let numbers = [];

    for(i=start; i <= end; i++) {

        numbers.push(i);

    }
    return numbers;
}
console.log(range(1,5));

function sum(arrayOfNumbers) {

    var sumOfNo = 0;

    for(i=0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
        
        sumOfNo += arrayOfNumbers[i];
    }

    return sumOfNo;
}
console.log(sum(range(10,15)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getSumFromRange(start, end) {
   return ((end * (end + 1)) / 2) - ((start * (start + 1)) / 2) + start;
}
console.log(getSumFromRange(1, 10));
```

JSFiddle : [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/dox82cw5/)

it will be the efficient way to find sum of range. using simple liner female, refer [The nth partial sum of the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)